# Oracle: How to create spfile.ora?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I read that `Oracle 9i` has `spfile.ora` by default, but I don't understand: why that file isn't in `Oracle 9i` by default.

I want to know how to create `spfile.ora` correctly in `Oracle 11g`?

Comment: If you started the DB with a pfile you can create spfile with `CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE = '$ORACLE_HOME/work/t_init1.ora';` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6016.htm

Comment: who sets dislike -\_/- ?

Comment: @vercelli , when i creating the file by that command CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE = '$ORACLE_HOME/work/t_init1.ora' , so file spfile<SID>.ora will create , not spfile.ora (((

Comment: Yes, that's by default. your spfile should be spfile<SID>.ora in order to be able to have more than 1 instance on your server.

Comment: Is it Oracle 9 or 11?  Your text says 9, but you tagged the question with version 11.

Comment: @sstan , Oracle 11. I'm simply forgot to add that note in my question ). Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be connected to your Oracle instance as `SYS`. 
Then use the following to create your `spfile`

```
CREATE SPFILE='/u01/oracle/dbs/spfile.ora'
FROM PFILE='/u01/oracle/dbs/init.ora';
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to create? RAC or standalone database.

In RAC follow the steps.
**Stop the database**
srvctl stop database -d test

Startup any one instance using existing pfile.
SQL> startup nomount pfile='/scratch/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs/inittest.ora';

Create spfile from pfile.
SQL> create spfile='+DATA/spfiletest.ora' from pfile='/scratch/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs/inittest.ora';

Stop and start the database
[oracle@orahow dbs]$ srvctl stop database -d test
[oracle@orahow dbs]$ srvctl start database -d test

Read full at: [Create spfile from pfile](https://orahow.com/create-spfile-from-pfile-in-asm/)